# htaccess rewriteRule, CSS and JS files calling html markup of full webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So I am dealing with cleaning up a url so the url param key is dropped leaving just the value.

I have no rewriteCond so this should execute unless I am missing something:

Currently navigating to the page will pull content, but all my css and js files are pulling mirrors of the html markup for the web page, in each external file. Would this be an htaccess issue or soemthing else?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/page\.php/([a-z-]+)$ /page.php?key=$1 [R=301]
</IfModule>
```

I have also tried using the flags [L,PT] so it does a passthrough and treats it as a uri. This did nothing as well.

Comment: Comment out this rule and see if things work fine or not?

Comment: no dice, it works fine when I leave /page.php?key=value in the url, but when I change it to page.php/value as I trying to map with htaccess, it gives me the results described

Comment: use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.

Comment: @anubhava Thanks a lot, that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a relative URL base to the header of your pages (between the `<head>` and `</head>` tags):

```
<base href="/" />
```

or

```
<base href="http://example.com/" />
```

(replacing your domain name with example.com